# Why do elements need to be continually added to GeometryModel3D property collections which have already been computed for rendering to occur?

Tags: c#, wpf, caching, rendering

Below follows a minimal, complete and verifiable example based on the issue I am encountering with WPF model rendering, here we are just rendering randomly distributed "particles" on an arbitrary 2D plane where each particle has a colour corresponding to its order of spawning.

---

**`MainWindow.cs`**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window {
    // prng for position generation
    private static Random rng = new Random();
    private readonly ComponentManager comp_manager;
    private List<Color> color_list;
    // counter for particle no.
    private int current_particles;

    public MainWindow() {
        InitializeComponent();
        comp_manager = new ComponentManager();
        current_particles = 0;
        color_list = new List<Color>();
    }
    // computes the colours corresponding to each particle in 
    // order based on a rough temperature-gradient
    private void ComputeColorList(int total_particles) {
        for (int i = 0; i < total_particles; ++i) {
            Color color = new Color();
            color.ScA = 1;
            color.ScR = (float)i / total_particles;
            color.ScB = 1 - (float)i / total_particles;
            color.ScG = (i < total_particles / 2) ? (float)i / total_particles : (1 - (float)i / total_particles);
            // populate color_list
            color_list.Add(color);
        }
    }
    // clear the simulation view and all Children of WorldModels
    private void Clear() {
        comp_manager.Clear();
        color_list.Clear();
        current_particles = 0;
        // clear Model3DCollection and re-add the ambient light
        // NOTE: WorldModels is a Model3DGroup declared in MainWindow.xaml
        WorldModels.Children.Clear();
        WorldModels.Children.Add(new AmbientLight(Colors.White));
    }
    private void Generate(int total) {
        const int min = -75;
        const int max = 75;
        // generate particles
        while (current_particles < total) {
            int rand_x = rng.Next(min, max);
            int rand_y = rng.Next(min, max);
            comp_manager.AddParticleToComponent(new Point3D(rand_x, rand_y, .0), 1.0);
            Dispatcher.Invoke(() => { comp_manager.Update(); });
            ++current_particles;
        }
    }
    // generate_button click handler
    private void OnGenerateClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
        if (current_particles > 0) Clear();
        int n_particles = (int)particles_slider.Value;
        // pre-compute colours of each particle
        ComputeColorList(n_particles);
        // add GeometryModel3D instances for each particle component to WorldModels (defined in the XAML code below)
        for (int i = 0; i < n_particles; ++i) {
            WorldModels.Children.Add(comp_manager.CreateComponent(color_list[i]));
        }
        // generate particles in separate thread purely to maintain
        // similarities between this minimal example and the actual code
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Generate(n_particles));
    }
}
```

---

**`ComponentManager.cs`**

This class provides a convenience object for managing a `List` of `Component` instances such that particles can be added and updates applied to each `Component` in the `List`.

```
public class ComponentManager {
    // also tried using an ObservableCollection<Component> but no difference
    private readonly List<Component> comp_list;
    private int id_counter = 0;
    private int current_counter = -1;
    
    public ComponentManager() {
        comp_list = new List<Component>();
    }
    public Model3D CreateComponent(Color color) {
        comp_list.Add(new Component(color, ++id_counter));
        // get the Model3D of most-recently-added Component and return it
        return comp_list[comp_list.Count - 1].ComponentModel;
    }
    public void AddParticleToComponent(Point3D pos, double size) {
        comp_list[++current_counter].SpawnParticle(pos, size);
    }
    public void Update() {
        // VERY SLOW, NEED WAY TO CACHE ALREADY RENDERED COMPONENTS
        foreach (var p in comp_list) { p.Update(); }
    }
    public void Clear() {
        id_counter = 0;
        current_counter = -1;
        foreach(var p in comp_list) { p.Clear(); }
        comp_list.Clear();
    }
}
```

---

**`Component.cs`**

This class represents the GUI model of a single particle instance with an associated `GeometryModel3D` giving the rendering properties of the particle (i.e. the material and thus colour as well as render target/visual).

```
// single particle of systems
public class Particle {
    public Point3D position;
    public double size;
}
public class Component {
    private GeometryModel3D component_model;
    private Point3DCollection positions;  // model Positions collection
    private Int32Collection triangles; // model TriangleIndices collection
    private PointCollection textures; // model TextureCoordinates collection
    private Particle p;
    private int id;
    // flag determining if this component has been rendered
    private bool is_done = false;

    public Component(Color _color, int _id) {
        p = null;
        id = _id;
        component_model = new GeometryModel3D { Geometry = new MeshGeometry3D() };
        Ellipse e = new Ellipse {
            Width = 32.0,
            Height = 32.0
        };
        RadialGradientBrush rb = new RadialGradientBrush();
        // set colours of the brush such that each particle has own colour
        rb.GradientStops.Add(new GradientStop(_color, 0.0));
        // fade boundary of particle
        rb.GradientStops.Add(new GradientStop(Colors.Black, 1.0));
        rb.Freeze();
        e.Fill = rb;
        e.Measure(new Size(32.0, 32.0));
        e.Arrange(new Rect(0.0, 0.0, 32.0, 32.0));
        // cached for increased performance
        e.CacheMode = new BitmapCache();
        BitmapCacheBrush bcb = new BitmapCacheBrush(e);
        DiffuseMaterial dm = new DiffuseMaterial(bcb);
        component_model.Material = dm;
        positions = new Point3DCollection();
        triangles = new Int32Collection();
        textures = new PointCollection();
        ((MeshGeometry3D)component_model.Geometry).Positions = positions;
        ((MeshGeometry3D)component_model.Geometry).TextureCoordinates = textures;
        ((MeshGeometry3D)component_model.Geometry).TriangleIndices = triangles;
    }
    public Model3D ComponentModel => component_model;
    public void Update() {
        if (p == null) return;
        if (!is_done) {
            int pos_index = id * 4;
            // compute positions 
            positions.Add(new Point3D(p.position.X, p.position.Y, p.position.Z));
            positions.Add(new Point3D(p.position.X, p.position.Y + p.size, p.position.Z));
            positions.Add(new Point3D(p.position.X + p.size, p.position.Y + p.size, p.position.Z));
            positions.Add(new Point3D(p.position.X + p.size, p.position.Y, p.position.Z));
            // compute texture co-ordinates
            textures.Add(new Point(0.0, 0.0));
            textures.Add(new Point(0.0, 1.0));
            textures.Add(new Point(1.0, 1.0));
            textures.Add(new Point(1.0, 0.0));
            // compute triangle indices
            triangles.Add(pos_index);
            triangles.Add(pos_index+2);
            triangles.Add(pos_index+1);
            triangles.Add(pos_index);
            triangles.Add(pos_index+3);
            triangles.Add(pos_index+2);
            // commenting out line below enables rendering of components but v. slow
            // due to continually filling up above collections
            is_done = true; 
        }
    }
    public void SpawnParticle(Point3D _pos, double _size) {
        p = new Particle {
            position = _pos,
            size = _size
        };
    }
    public void Clear() {
        ((MeshGeometry3D)component_model.Geometry).Positions.Clear();
        ((MeshGeometry3D)component_model.Geometry).TextureCoordinates.Clear();
        ((MeshGeometry3D)component_model.Geometry).TriangleIndices.Clear();
    }
}
```

---

**`MainWindow.xaml`**

The (crude) XAML code just for completeness in case anyone wants to verify this example.

```
<Window x:Class="GraphicsTestingWPF.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:GraphicsTestingWPF"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="768" Width="1366">
<Grid>
    <Grid Background="Black" Visibility="Visible" Width ="Auto" Height="Auto" Margin="5,3,623,10" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
        <Viewport3D Name="World" Focusable="True">
            <Viewport3D.Camera>
                <OrthographicCamera x:Name="orthograghic_camera" Position="0,0,32" LookDirection="0,0,-32" UpDirection="0,1,0" Width="256"/>
            </Viewport3D.Camera>

            <Viewport3D.Children>
                <ModelVisual3D>
                    <ModelVisual3D.Content>
                        <Model3DGroup x:Name="WorldModels">
                            <AmbientLight Color="#FFFFFFFF" />
                        </Model3DGroup>
                    </ModelVisual3D.Content>
                </ModelVisual3D>
            </Viewport3D.Children>
        </Viewport3D>
    </Grid>
    <Slider Maximum="1000" TickPlacement="BottomRight" TickFrequency="50" IsSnapToTickEnabled="True" x:Name="particles_slider" Margin="0,33,130,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="337"/>
    <Label x:Name="NParticles_Label" Content="Number of Particles" Margin="0,29,472,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" RenderTransformOrigin="1.019,-0.647" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="123"/>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding ElementName=particles_slider, Path=Value, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" x:Name="particle_val" Height="23" Margin="0,32,85,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" TextAlignment="Right" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="40"/>
    <Button x:Name="generate_button" Content="Generate" Margin="0,86,520,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="OnGenerateClick" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="75"/>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

---

**Problem**

As you may have surmised from the code, the issue lies in the `Update` methods of `ComponentManager` and `Component`. In order for the rendering to be successful I have to update each and every `Component` every time a particle is added to the system of particles - I tried to mitigate any performance issues from this by using the flag `is_done` in the class `Component`, to be set to true when the particle properties (`positions`, `textures` and `triangles`) were calculated the first time. Then, or so I thought, on each subsequent call to `Component::Update()` for a component the previously calculated values of these collections would be used.

However, this does not work here as setting `is_done` to true as explained above will simply cause nothing to be rendered. If I comment out `is_done = true;` then everything is rendered however it is incredibly slow - most likely due to the huge number of elements being added to the `positions` etc. collections of each `Component` (memory usage explodes as shown by the debugger diagnostics).

---

**Question**

> Why do I have to keep adding previously calculated elements to these collections for rendering to occur?
>
> In other words, why does it not just take the already calculated `Positions`, `TextureCoordinates` and `TriangleIndices` from each `Component` and use these when rendering?

Comment: You're missing the closing window tag in the XAML. Where is WorldModels declared?

Comment: Is your intention that each time click is generated, additional particles are added to the collection, because currently Clear() is called every time recreating your collection?

Comment: @DamianGreen I'll correct that, `WorldModels` is declared in the XAML code as a `Model3DGroup`. Also, no each click of the generate button is supposed to create a single system of particles - any subsequent clicks should clear the previous and create a new one; this is similar to how the actual code from which this problem is derived works.

Comment: The `ComputeColorList` method has `<= _total_particles` but that would make 201 elements (if 200 is selected). Is that right?

Comment: @Zack Ah that's probably just a typo, doesn't matter much in this case but I'll edit it for correctness now.

Answer (score 5):

It looks like there may be several problems here.

The first that I found was that you're calling `comp_mgr.Update()` *every time* you add a particle.  This, in turn, calls `Update()` on *every* particle.  All of that results in an O(n^2) operation which means that for 200 particles (your min), you're running the component update logic 40,000 times.  This is definitely what's causing it to be slow.

To eliminate this, I moved the `comp_mgr.Update()` call out of the while loop.  But then I got no points, just like when you uncomment the `is_done = true;` line.

Interestingly, when I added a second call to `comp_mgr.Update()`, I got a single point.  And with successive calls I got an additional point with each call.  This implies that, even with the slower code, you're still only getting 199 points on the 200-point setting.

There seems to be a deeper issue somewhere, but I'm unable to find it.  I'll update if I do.  Maybe this will lead you or someone else to the answer.

For now, the `MainWindow.Generate()` method looks like this:

```
private void Generate(int _total)
{
    const int min = -75;
    const int max = 75;
    // generate particles
    while (current_particles < _total)
    {
        int rand_x = rng.Next(min, max);
        int rand_y = rng.Next(min, max);
        comp_manager.AddParticleToComponent(new Point3D(rand_x, rand_y, .0), 1.0);
        ++current_particles;
    }
    Dispatcher.Invoke(() => { comp_manager.Update(); });
}
```

where replicating the `Update()` call *n* times results in *n*-1 points being rendered.

Comment: I see, that would go some way to explaining the performance issues. The problem is, however, that in the actual code from which this minimal problem is derived the code executed in the `while` loop is native C++ code, run in a separate thread, which is very computationally intensive - therefore to achieve a real time simulation I cannot just `Update` the model/GUI after the loop has finished executing.

Comment: With only moving the `comp_manager.Update()` call, I'm not seeing any particles rendered. Do you also comment out the `is_done` line in `Component::Render`?

Comment: but to clarify you wouldn't want to do the particle update function in the while loop still? @gregsdennis makes a good point

Comment: @Zack, no, I was not commenting out that line.  That's how I started noticing the *n*-1 behavior I mentioned.

Comment: @ArchbishopOfBanterbury, are you saying that you don't have access to the native C++ code to change how the loop works?

Comment: No, I do have access to the C++ code - but I can't see how that helps me here. If you're curious, you can find the full code [here](https://github.com/SJR276/DLAProject), where the C++ particle generating code can be found in `DLA_2d.cpp` in the `DLA_2d::generate` method.

Comment: @ArchbishopOfBanterbury It would be useful to know which code can be modified to find a solution.

Comment: Well I can modify any of the code I linked as it's all mine (if that's what you mean), but as I implied previously - I don't see how modifying the generation loop in the C++ code will help with this problem as I can't access the UI anywhere from this code (it is just a class library which gets called from the C# code). Essentially the main problem here is I just don't understand why I have to continuously add elements to the containers of the `component_model` for rendering to occur - and it appears you came across the same issue in your answer above.

Comment: @ArchbishopOfBanterbury, yeah, that confuses me as well.  It seems like your `is_done` logic should take care of the processing time problem, but I don't know what's going on behind the scenes in WPF 3D that might be causing the rendering issue.